# Use "RewriteEngine on" in .htaccess only if the visitor is in a session

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So a user who is not logged will see the same link as a user who is logged, the difference is that the logged user will see a different page after following the link.

Please note that I would like the link to stay intact, meaning that I don't want to replace the final url with another one. Also, I would like to avoid playing with cookies.

If it can't be done using rewriteengine, is there another way involving .htaccess / php?

Answer (score 0):

No need for anything related to .htaccess.

Combine both pages into one and wrap the content that only logged in users should see with something like `if logged_in() {...}` or whatever you can use to check if the user is logged in.

That should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

NO.

I'm not aware that its possible without cookies.

Or you can read session to `HTTP_SESSION` environment variable using `mod_session`

> If configured, the session can be read back from the HTTP_SESSION environment variable. By default, the session is kept private, so this has to be explicitly turned on with the SessionEnv directive.
>   Read from a session
>
> ```
> Session On
> SessionEnv On
> SessionCookieName session path=/
> SessionHeader X-Replace-Session
> ```
>
> Once read, the CGI variable HTTP_SESSION should contain the value key1=foo&key3=bar.

See the apache manual for [mod_session](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_session.html) for more info how to read session into the `HTTP_SESSION` env. variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. I am using rewriteengine to point the js file to a php file and then in that php file, i echo the appropriate javascript depending on the existance of a session.

Cool, considering that the code calls the .js file but in reality it is a php file that just echoes the js code.